# Website on Azure Virtual Machine stops responding every day

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have a website (orders.cpidealers.com) running on an Azure Virtual Machine currently configured to Basic, A2 (2 cores, 3.5 GB memory) monitoring 3 endpoints.

Every morning since Tuesday, June 24,

- The website has been unavailable (the browser just spins, I don't even get a 401 or any error)
- I can't RDP into the virtual machine,
- The endpoint status shows a warning triangle (although when I click on the link next to it some say Not Available while others give a time, I'm not sure I know how to translate the endpoint status box).

To resolve the problem, I login to Azure and restart the Virtual Machine. So far, everything seems to work fine for the remainder of the day until I arrive to work in the morning at 7:30 (Mountain Time).

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the system was hanging as Rouen mentioned. From that, we found this article which seems to have resolved the problem: [IIS: Web Application hangs periodically needs system reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863059/iis-web-application-hangs-periodically-needs-system-reboot)

Here is everything my developer did:

> I changed a few other things on the server. Set the sql server to never auto close, which should help the performance in the morning, set the gupdate to manual ( we did that together ) and then I found this article, which seems an exact case for our problem so I set the Credentials Manager to automatic and restarted.

[IIS: Web Application hangs periodically needs system reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863059/iis-web-application-hangs-periodically-needs-system-reboot)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to me like your app somehow manages to hang IIS by wasting resources. Cant tell you more without any data. You should enable some performance counters monitoring and see what is going on.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-use-performance-counters/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/303686/Windows-Azure-Diagnostics-Performance-Counters-In

Comment: Thank you Rouen, I looked over the articles you included and sent them to my developer. As for the problem, it looks like you were correct. The system was hanging and we were able to find a solution for that.